# らせる typo for される or different word?

Tags: grammar

> 暴風は擬神化された龍の如く、廊下と髑髏の面を飲み込もうと、その蛇体を螺旋**らせる**。
>
> The strong wind, similarly to the quasi-deified dragon, makes its serpentine body twist like a spiral with the intention of swallowing the corridor and the (man) with the skull mask.

I think this could be an acceptable translation, but I consider らせる as a typo for される.
Is it another form completely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

螺旋 is not a suru-verb and らせんさせる doesn't make sense anyway.

If it's not a typo, maybe the author wanted it to be read as [くねらせる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/62612/meaning/m0u/). Does the author of this novel like "creative" 当て字 readings like this? Anyway, I don't know why this doesn't come with furigana.

Comment: He does like 当て字, 
It might be like you said, it makes sense if it's くならせる.

Comment: Or maybe ねじらせる, よじらせる.